# Is This a New Property I Have Found Pertaining to Mersenne Primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures, primality-test, mersenne-numbers

While playing with Mersenne numbers, I found the following property distinguishing Mersenne prime numbers from Mersenne composite numbers.

A Mersenne number, $\text{M}p$, is a number of the form $2^p - 1$, where $p$ is prime.

### Property

For $p > 2$, Mersenne primes can be expressed as
\begin{align*}
 \text{M}p = \frac{a^3 + b^3}{a + b}\text{,}
\end{align*}
where $a$ and $b$ are integers, $a \neq -b$,
with exactly $12$ different solutions.
So far, also $\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)=1$ holds for Mersenne primes.

Mersenne composites have either no integer solution or more than $12$ solutions ($24$ so far).
Also $\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)=1$ does not hold if the integer solutions exist so far.

### Examples

\begin{align*}
\text{M}5 &= \frac{6^3 + 5^3}{11} = 31 \\
\text{M}7 &= 7^3 - 6^3 = 127
\end{align*}

The M11 has no integer solution for $(a,b)$.

The M37 has 24 solutions and also $\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)=1$ does not hold.

### Remarks

- Except the M2, twelve solutions exist for each Mersenne prime.
  If $(a,b)$ is a solution, then also $(-a,-b)$, $(b,a)$, and $(-b,-a)$ are.
- Since
  \begin{align*}
   \frac{a^3 + b^3}{a + b} = a^2 -ab + b^2 \text{,}
  \end{align*}
  each Mersenne prime has an ellipse intersecting integer grid associated with it.
  For example, $-a^2 + ab - b^2 + 127 = 0$ is the ellipse for M7.

### Results

Solutions for the first few Mersenne numbers:
$$\begin{matrix}
p & \text{M}p & (a,b) \\
\hline
2 &          3 & (1,2) \\
  3 &          7 & (1,-2), (1,3), (2,3) \\
  5 &         31 & (1,-5), (1,6), (5,6) \\
  7 &        127 & (6,-7), (6,13), (7,13) \\
 11 &       2047 & \text{no solution} \\
 13 &       8191 & (1,-90), (1,91), (90,91) \\
 17 &     131071 & (6,-359), (6,365), (359,365) \\
 19 &     524287 & (83,-679), (83, 762), (679, 762) \\
 23 &    8388607 & \text{no solution} \\
 29 &  536870911 & \text{no solution} \\
 31 & 2147483647 & (4698, 43813), (4698,48511), (43813, 48511) \\
 37 & 137438953471 & \text{24 solutions} \\
 41 & 2199023255551 & \text{no solution} \\
 43 & 8796093022207 & \text{no solution} \\
   ... & ... & ... \\
\end{matrix}$$

I have verified the conjecture using WolframAlpha for all $p$ below 100.

### Question

Can you confirm this result?
Is this known?
Any feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you observe, this is about representing $M_p$ by the quadratic form $a^2-ab+b^2$. That is the norm of the quadratic integer $a+b\omega$ where $\omega
=\frac12(-1+i\sqrt3)$. A prime $q$ with $q\equiv1\pmod 3$ always has twelve
representations by this form: there are two ideals of norm $q$ in $\Bbb Z[\omega]$
and each has six different generators. Indeed there is a formula for the number
of representations $q$ by this in terms  of the factorisation of $q$. The number of representations is only $12$ if $q=q'm^2$ where $q'$ is a prime congruent to $1$
modulo $3$ and the prime factors of $m$ are all congruent to $2$ modulo $3$.
I can't see why it's impossible for a Mersenne number to have such a factorisation with $m>1$, but it does seem rather unlikely.

Comment: Nice answer! In any case, every Mersenne composite (Mersenne number that is composite) I have tested so far has either 24 solutions or no solution at all. Mersenne primes always have 12 solutions of the form $(a^3 + b^3)/(a + b)$ a no solution of the form $(a^2 + b^2)/(a + b)$. Is there any reason for non-existence of this second form?